# Can't use lombok @NoArgsConstructor on a class

Tags: java, jackson, lombok

I'm using Jackson as a Json parser and I'm getting an error:

```
No suitable constructor found for type ~ can not instantiate from JSON object
```

So I've tried adding `@NoArgsConstructor`, but now I'm getting this one:

```
constructor AccountItem in class AccountItem cannot be applied to given types
```

Here's my class:

```
@Getter
@Builder
public class AccountItem {

/**
 * Accounti dentifier
 */
private Long accountId;

/**
 * Account name
 */
private String accountName;

/**
 * Account priority
 */
private int accountPriority;
}
```

What might be the cause?

Comment: Can you try `@NoArgsConstructor` without `@Builder`?

Comment: It works without a `@Builder`, but the fact is I really need this one.

Comment: Which version of _lombok_ are you using?

Comment: And if you omit `@NoArgsConstructor` and add the default constructor yourself, does it work?

Comment: If using the builder. You need to add @AllArgsConstructor. So you need both.
'@AllArgsConstructor'
'@NoArgsConstructor'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add both `@AllArgsConstructor` and `@NoArgsConstructor` annotations to your class

Answer (score 1):

It's known issue from lombok version 1.16.20. https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1563

You can do this:

```
@Getter
@Builder
@JsonDeserialize(builder = AccountItem.AccountItemBuilder.class)
public class AccountItem {

    /**
     * Accounti dentifier
     */
    private Long accountId;

    /**
     * Account name
     */
    private String accountName;

    /**
     * Account priority
     */
    private int accountPriority;

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static final class AccountItemBuilder {
    }
}
```